# Is there a way to list the settings for an existing JQuery UI .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a project that has been going for many years. We currently use jquery 1.7.2 and a custom jqueryUI 1.8.21. I am creating a new feature that requires we upgrade jquery, so I am in the process of upgrading to jquery 1.9.1.

The problem is that 1.9.1 isn't compatible with UI 1.8.21, so I need to upgrade UI too. Alright, not a big deal... except that we have a bunch of custom settings in that UI 1.8.21 file, and I need to carry them forward to the new version.

I could recreate the custom theme from scratch using the new UI 1.12.1 version, but it would be very hard and there is always the chance that I will miss some important setting. I am looking for a way to list out the modified settings in the existing file to easily apply them to a customization of the newer version, or to somehow upgrade or recreate the same setting with the newer version.

Is there a tool or automatic way to do this, or am I out of luck and need to just recreate it by hand?

Comment: I haven't created any custom jQuery UI themes, but I'll bet there's a comment at the beginning of the .js file that lists the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download a theme created with ThemeRoller, one of the files is `jquery-ui.theme.css`. The comment at the beginning has a line like this:

```
 * To view and modify this theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?scope=&folderName=custom-theme&bgImgOpacityError=&bgImgOpacityHighlight=&bgImgOpacityActive=&bgImgOpacityHover=&bgImgOpacityDefault=&bgImgOpacityContent=50&bgImgOpacityHeader=&cornerRadiusShadow=8px&offsetLeftShadow=0px&offsetTopShadow=0px&thicknessShadow=5px&opacityShadow=30&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&bgTextureShadow=flat&bgColorShadow=%23666666&opacityOverlay=30&bgImgOpacityOverlay=0&bgTextureOverlay=flat&bgColorOverlay=%23aaaaaa&iconColorError=%23cc0000&fcError=%235f3f3f&borderColorError=%23f1a899&bgTextureError=flat&bgColorError=%23fddfdf&iconColorHighlight=%23777620&fcHighlight=%23777620&borderColorHighlight=%23dad55e&bgTextureHighlight=flat&bgColorHighlight=%23fffa90&iconColorActive=%23ffffff&fcActive=%23ffffff&borderColorActive=%23003eff&bgTextureActive=flat&bgColorActive=%23007fff&iconColorHover=%23555555&fcHover=%232b2b2b&borderColorHover=%23cccccc&bgTextureHover=flat&bgColorHover=%23ededed&iconColorDefault=%23777777&fcDefault=%23454545&borderColorDefault=%23c5c5c5&bgTextureDefault=flat&bgColorDefault=%23f6f6f6&iconColorContent=%23444444&fcContent=%23333333&borderColorContent=%23dddddd&bgTextureContent=flat&bgColorContent=%23ffffff&iconColorHeader=%23444444&fcHeader=%23333333&borderColorHeader=%23dddddd&bgTextureHeader=flat&bgColorHeader=%23e9e9e9&cornerRadius=10px&fwDefault=normal&fsDefault=1em&ffDefault=Arial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif
```

Follow that link, click the **Download Theme** button, and you'll be able to download a new version with the same theme.

However, this only specifies the theme. The download page that the button goes to requires you to select the components to include. I don't see any automated way to do that, but there's a comment at the beginning of `jquery-ui.js` with a line like:

```
* Includes: widget.js, position.js, data.js, disable-selection.js, focusable.js, form-reset-mixin.js, jquery-1-7.js, keycode.js, labels.js, scroll-parent.js, tabbable.js, unique-id.js, widgets/accordion.js, widgets/autocomplete.js, widgets/button.js, widgets/checkboxradio.js, widgets/controlgroup.js, widgets/datepicker.js, widgets/menu.js, widgets/mouse.js, widgets/progressbar.js, widgets/selectmenu.js, widgets/slider.js, widgets/spinner.js, widgets/tabs.js, widgets/tooltip.js
```

You may be able to figure out which components to select from this.

Comment: I found the link to recreate the theme, unfortunately it didn't preserve some of the customizations we had. Selecting the included components was easy to do though.

Comment: If you made local customizations to the theme, there's no way ThemeBuilder could know about them. Perhaps you could download the old and new versions of the theme, then use `diff` to create a patch file between them, and apply that to your CSS file.

Comment: For the future, it would be best if you put local customizations in a separate file that's loaded after the ones you download.

Comment: I had hoped that we didn't have local customizations, that they were all part of the ThemeBuilder. Alas, that seems to not be the case, or that the defaults have been changed in the last 10 years.